# Is there a way to list all I/O-resources?

Tags: linux

Is there a way to list all I/O-resources ? I.e. to list all memory-mapped registers, all I/O port mapped registers and all interrupts of all devices ?

Comment: Where's such a tool for Linux ? And I'll bet my right hand that this information is somewhere inside the /proc-interface.

Comment: ,, there are many tools for Linux that show system information, such as those at https://alternativeto.net/software/hwinfo32/?platform=linux . such as hwinfo, https://alternativeto.net/software/hwinfo/about/ .